# Number Guessing Game in Python

Tags: python, random

I was trying to create a simple random number guessing game. The problem is even if I type the correct number it replies with a 'The number is less than'. Can somebody provide me a solution for this one ?

Thanks in advance

```
import random
import sys

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
user = raw_input('Guess The Number\n Pick between 1 - 10\n >>> ')
try:
    int(user)
except:
    print "Numbers Only !"
    sys.exit(0)
number = random.choice(numbers)
int(number)
for i in range(0, 4):
    if number == user:
        print 'You Won!'
    if user > number:
        print 'The number is less than', user
        user = raw_input('>>> ')
        try:
            int(user)
        except:
            print "Numbers Only !"
    if user < number:
        print 'The number is bigger than', user
        user = raw_input('>>> ')
        int(user)

print "The Number was", number
```

Comment: You can have a look at a solution done using functions at <https://github.com/hjupadhyay/guessthenumber/>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The biggest problem is that you're not saving the conversion to `int` so you're using the guess as the string the user entered.  You need to save it by doing `user = int(raw_input('>>>'))`

There are other ways you can improve this code, however.  You repeat yourself a bit, and you  don't need `random.choice`, you can use `random.randrange(1, 10)`

You shouldn't just say `except:`.  You wanna only catch the exceptions you are looking for.  The particular exception you are looking for is a `ValueError`

Additionally, I suggest you let the user try again when they enter something that's not a number.  You can wrap up the whole thing in it's own function.

```
import random

def get_user_num(msg='>>> '): 
    """Print the msg parameter as a prompt for the user to enter a number.  If
    they enter an invalid string, reprompt them until they enter a number.

    """
    while True: 
        try: 
            return int(raw_input(msg)) # save the conversion to int
        except ValueError: # only except the error you're actually looking for
            print 'Numbers Only!' 

# 'from 1-9' is probably better than 'between 1-10'
user = get_user_num('Guess The Number\n Pick from 1-9\n>>> ') 
number = random.randrange(1, 10) # <- numbers list is unnecessary
#int(number) # this conversion was never needed, it was already a number

for _ in range(4):  # you don't need (0, 4), 0 is assumed 
    if number == user:
        print 'You Won!' # the correct number has been guessed
        break # exit the loop once the number has been correctly guessed
    elif user > number:
        print 'The number is less than', user
    elif user < number:
        print 'The number is bigger than', user

    # Don't repeat yourself, put this outside the `if`s
    user = get_user_num()
else:
    #only print the answer when it wasn't guessed correctly
    print "The Number was", number
```

Comment: This deserves many more upvotes for going way above and beyond the call of duty :)

Comment: `randrange(1, 10)` returns integers in `[1, 9]`. You might mean `randint(1, 10)` or `"Pick between 1 - 10"` is misleading.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I realized this as well, but OP's list is [1..9] and I didn't wanna change his string.  I would suggest changing it to `'Pick a number from 1-9'`

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback. It is much appreciated.

Comment: nitpicking, but: True has to be capitalized, and I believe "user = int(raw_input(msg))" could be "return int(raw_input(msg))" as the statement is evaluated before trying to return

Answer (score 6):

When you convert to int(user), you aren't saving a new int to user. So user still remains a string.

What you need to do is

```
user = int(user)
```

By the way, this is for all of the places where you use int(user)

Answer (score 3):

This could be done with a much simpler implementation:

```
import random

number = random.randrange(10)
for i in xrange(4):
    try:
        user = int(raw_input('guess: '))
    except ValueError:
        print 'must be int'
        continue
    if user == number:
        print 'bravo'
        break
    elif user < number:
        print 'greater'
    else:
        print 'lesser'
print 'it was: %d' % number
```

Comment: `random.randrange` is all you need to pick a number.  You need a `continue` at the end of the `except` block